# Azure Data Factory Linked Service Issue

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to parameterized the linked service for the Blob Storage in Azure Data Factory. I have tried two option. The first one using the "Connection String - Enter Manually", and it works. For the second I'm using the "Azure Key Vault" option. However, the second one fails. The thing is, for the client requirement I need to use the this one. I suppose the Secret Name is not the problem given that the first option does not have any problem, but what could be missing or failing?

[image]

Comment: In the 2nd example, what happens if you just hardcore the `secret name`? Does it give the same error?

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks for your reply. Yes, I'm also getting an error.

Comment: Can you copy the connectionstring again?